# Plot scipy.signal.find_peaks graph with datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I would like to use `scipy.signal.find_peaks` to find peaks for `Value` in `df` as shown below.

df:

```
  index Timestamp               Value   Id
0   36  2020-11-08 23:30:40.370 45.5    15
1   47  2020-11-13 04:52:29.410 44.5    15
2   67  2020-12-01 22:17:50.300 42.5    20
3   129 2020-11-24 00:57:11.950 43.0    103
4   176 2020-12-03 01:40:16.250 42.0    87
5   246 2020-11-12 07:32:54.000 43.5    103
6   281 2020-11-30 21:13:07.630 45.5    15
7   335 2020-11-30 20:43:11.050 43.5    15
8   370 2020-11-09 06:04:19.630 45.0    15
9   375 2020-11-22 21:21:33.150 44.0    115
10  384 2020-11-23 22:04:44.580 40.5    20
11  408 2020-11-16 03:26:10.150 46.0    15
12  428 2020-12-07 02:04:42.890 46.5    15
13  437 2020-11-26 00:10:34.660 47.0    15
14  482 2020-11-26 04:14:23.180 46.0    15
15  500 2020-12-06 19:40:30.580 46.0    15
16  528 2020-11-26 02:17:27.110 47.5    15
17  585 2020-11-25 18:13:17.450 43.0    15
18  641 2020-11-26 20:02:13.170 46.0    15
19  647 2020-11-11 21:36:09.530 41.0    112
```

reproducible example:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: 36,
  1: 47,
  2: 67,
  3: 129,
  4: 176,
  5: 246,
  6: 281,
  7: 335,
  8: 370,
  9: 375,
  10: 384,
  11: 408,
  12: 428,
  13: 437,
  14: 482,
  15: 500,
  16: 528,
  17: 585,
  18: 641,
  19: 647},
 'Timestamp': {0: Timestamp('2020-11-08 23:30:40.370000'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-11-13 04:52:29.410000'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-12-01 22:17:50.300000'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-11-24 00:57:11.950000'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-12-03 01:40:16.250000'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-11-12 07:32:54'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-11-30 21:13:07.630000'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-11-30 20:43:11.050000'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-11-09 06:04:19.630000'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-11-22 21:21:33.150000'),
  10: Timestamp('2020-11-23 22:04:44.580000'),
  11: Timestamp('2020-11-16 03:26:10.150000'),
  12: Timestamp('2020-11-07 02:04:42.890000'),
  13: Timestamp('2020-11-26 00:10:34.660000'),
  14: Timestamp('2020-11-26 04:14:23.180000'),
  15: Timestamp('2020-12-06 19:40:30.580000'),
  16: Timestamp('2020-12-26 02:17:27.110000'),
  17: Timestamp('2020-11-25 18:13:17.450000'),
  18: Timestamp('2020-11-26 20:02:13.170000'),
  19: Timestamp('2020-11-11 21:36:09.530000')},
 'Value': {0: 45.5,
  1: 44.5,
  2: 42.5,
  3: 43.0,
  4: 42.0,
  5: 43.5,
  6: 45.5,
  7: 43.5,
  8: 45.0,
  9: 44.0,
  10: 40.5,
  11: 46.0,
  12: 46.5,
  13: 47.0,
  14: 46.0,
  15: 46.0,
  16: 47.5,
  17: 43.0,
  18: 46.0,
  19: 41.0},
 'Id': {0: 15,
  1: 15,
  2: 20,
  3: 103,
  4: 87,
  5: 103,
  6: 15,
  7: 15,
  8: 15,
  9: 115,
  10: 20,
  11: 15,
  12: 15,
  13: 15,
  14: 15,
  15: 15,
  16: 15,
  17: 15,
  18: 15,
  19: 112}})
```

Using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = df['Value'].values
peaks, properties = find_peaks(x, prominence=0.1, width=1)
properties["prominences"], properties["widths"]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.vlines(x=peaks, ymin=x[peaks] - properties["prominences"],
           ymax = x[peaks], color = "C1")
plt.hlines(y=properties["width_heights"], xmin=properties["left_ips"],
           xmax=properties["right_ips"], color = "C1")
plt.show()
```

and the output is below, which only considered the `Value` column.
[image]

How can I make `Timestamp` the horizontal axis?

---

Edit:

I tried to make `Timestamp` the index and changed the x- and y- axis accordingly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

z = df
z.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
z.index.to_pydatetime()
peaks, properties = find_peaks(z.Value, prominence=0.1, width=1)
properties["prominences"], properties["widths"]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
plt.plot_date(z.index, z.Value)
plt.plot_date(z.index[peaks], z.Value[peaks], "x")
plt.vlines(x=z.index[peaks], ymin=z.Value[peaks] - properties["prominences"],
           ymax = z.index[peaks], color = "C1")
plt.hlines(y=properties["width_heights"], xmin=properties["left_ips"],
           xmax=properties["right_ips"], color = "C1")
plt.show()
```

which returned:
[image]

What could have gone wrong?

---

Edit 2:
Using @Asmus's solution on a larger dataset, I noticed that the graph changed completely when I changed the `prominence` and `width`. For instance, in the graph below I used `prominence== 5` and `width==0.0001157`, for `Value > 30` because I'm interested in peaks above 30 for `Value`, and have a prominence of around 5 and width of 0.0001157, which is 10 seconds as a fraction of a day.

[image]

Then if I changed `prominence` to 10, it looks like this:
[image]

Both look very differently from the original data, as below:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your `df` is not sorted by `Timestamp`, hence the peaks you've found so far are valid only in "index-space", so to speak. Else, you should be able to convert the found indices to Timestamps simply by `df.loc[indices,'Timestamp']` and plot everything on the correct axis: `plt.plot(df['Timestamp'],x)`, and so on.

Comment: @Asmus May I ask what `indices` is? Do I have to reset `Timestamp` as the index? Would you please show me in some code?

Comment: I've appended my answer again, explaining why you need to resample. Perhaps in your specific case, you could try with a finer interpolation argument like `'min'`, see my update below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regarding find_peaks() and indices:

Ok, so if we have a look at the [documentation for `find_peaks()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), we see that it

> takes a 1-D array and finds all local maxima by simple comparison of neighboring values

and returns

> Indices of peaks in x that satisfy all given conditions.

So, running for example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([4,5,6,7,6,5,5])
idx, properties = find_peaks(x)
print(idx, x[idx])
```

yields: `[3]` (the index) and `[7]` as the value.

---

### Regarding ordering the data:

In your case, you're trying to fit data as a function of dates, i.e. we first need to make sure your data is *ordered* correctly - if you run this:

```
x = df['Timestamp'].values
y = df['Value'].values
idx, properties = find_peaks(y, prominence=0.1, width=1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(10,3))

# that is your original plot:
axes[0].plot(y)
axes[0].plot(idx,y[idx],"x")
axes[0].set_title("unsorted, x = indices")

# here, I simply use the "correct" data as x-axis
axes[1].plot(x,y)
axes[1].plot(x[idx], y[idx], "x")
axes[1].set_title("unsorted, x = dates")

# and now I also sort the data:
df = df.sort_values(by="Timestamp")
x = df['Timestamp'].values
y = df['Value'].values
idx, properties = find_peaks(y, prominence=0.1, width=1)
axes[2].plot(x,y)
axes[2].plot(x[idx], y[idx], "x")
axes[2].set_title("sorted, x = dates")

# some nicer formatting:
for ax in axes:
    ax.grid()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You'll see this:[image: Differences in x-axis]

That is (from left to right):

1. The data as you plotted it, as a function of the index (i.e. x goes from 0 to 19). Here you have no issues finding peaks and highlighting them.
2. The data plotted as a function of `x=df['Timestamp']` - it looks chaotic because your DataFrame is not ordered in time!
3. The sorted DataFrame, plotted as a function of the Timestamp, using `x[idx], y[idx]` to highlight the locations of peaks.

---

### Regarding hlines and vlines on a date axis

Now you should be able to add vertical lines without much issue with:

```
axes[0].vlines(x=x[idx], ymin=y[idx] - properties["prominences"],
           ymax = y[idx], color = "C1")
```

But in case of the horizontal lines, the issue becomes that `properties` looks like this:

```
{
    'prominences': array([5., 5.]), 
    'left_bases': array([3, 8]), 
    'right_bases': array([ 8, 17]), 
    'widths': array([3.14285714, 3.225]), 
    'width_heights': array([43.5, 44.5]), 
    'left_ips': array([ 4., 10.375]), 
    'right_ips': array([ 7.14285714, 13.6])
}
```

Where it's obviously "unclear" for `matplotlib` what e.g. a `width` of `3.14285714` means in term of dates, at least without proper conversion into dates.

---

### Edit: How to work with missing data to fix the `hlines`

First of all, you'll need to make sure that all dates in the date range have valid data, so that you can directly interpret the return values from `find_peaks()` as relative dates (that is if it finds a peak at index "2" you'd directly be able to convert this to [start_date + 2 days]).

```
# print(df.head()) ## <-- see the unordered df
# first, make sure that the DataFrame is sorted by date
df = df.sort_values(by='Timestamp').set_index('Timestamp')
# print(df.head()) ## <-- it is now ordered, but there are missing dates
# and then resample it on a daily basis, 
# using mean() to average multiple entries per day:
df = df.resample('D').mean().reset_index()
# print(df.head()) ## <-- it is sorted and every day is present, but still some 'Value' are missing

x = df['Timestamp']
# since we have missing data, interpolate the values linearly:
y = df['Value'].interpolate()

# now find the peaks
idx, properties = find_peaks(y, prominence=0.1, width=1)
# note that since we interpolated the data on a daily basis,
# "idx" is now equivalent to "days since the first date"!

# introduce some shorthands:
l = properties["left_ips"]
r = properties["right_ips"]
p = properties["prominences"]
w = properties["widths"]
wh = properties["width_heights"]

peak_x = x.iloc[idx] 
peak_y = y.iloc[idx]

def to_date(x):
    """
    takes the first Timestamp of the df as a start date
    and then converts a given relative date x (in days)  
    back into a "normal" date
    
    Note how this only works since we resampled the df on a daily basis!
    """
    _start = df.loc[0,'Timestamp']
    return pd.to_datetime(_start) + pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='D')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))    

ax.plot(x,y,c="b",zorder=0)
ax.scatter(x[df['Value'].isna()],y[df['Value'].isna()],
    edgecolors="r",facecolors="none",marker='o',zorder=1,label="interpolated!") # to highlight interpolated dates    
ax.scatter(peak_x, peak_y, color="C1", marker="x", s=200,zorder=2)
ax.vlines(x=peak_x, ymin=peak_y - p, ymax = peak_y, color = "C1")

ax.hlines(y=wh, xmin=to_date(l), xmax=to_date(r), color = "C1")

ax.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Yields:

[image: Final solution, peaks on a datetime scale]

**Note:** I emphasised the interpolated datapoints (additional red circles which are not present in your original dataframe.) and remember that some `Values` got averaged by `resample('D').mean()` above, so you need to check whether this actually suites your needs!

---

### A last demonstration:

Ok, so in order to highlight was I was meaning, let's use a reduced example:

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-03 12:45:00", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01"])
ys = [0, 1, 4, 3, 2.7, 2, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':ts, 'Value':ys})
print(df)

idx, properties = find_peaks(df['Value'], prominence=0.1, width=0.1)
# introduce some shorthands:
l = properties["left_ips"]
r = properties["right_ips"]
p = properties["prominences"]
w = properties["widths"]
wh = properties["width_heights"]

peak_x = df['Timestamp'][idx].values
peak_y = df['Value'][idx].values

print(f"Found a peak at {idx} (index), i.e. at {peak_x} (Timestamp) with height {peak_y} (Value)")
print(f"Half of the peak maximum can be found at {wh} (Value) and has a width of {w} (Index)!")
print(f"The width starts at {l} (index) and goes to {r} (index) == ?? (INTERPOLATION OF INDEX REQUIRED!)")

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))    
ax.plot(df['Timestamp'],df['Value'], marker="o")

ax.scatter(peak_x, peak_y, marker="x", s=20**2,color="r")

ax.vlines(x=peak_x, ymin=peak_y - p, ymax = peak_y, color = "C1")
ax.axhline(wh,color="g",linestyle="dashed")

fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here, the DataFrame looks like this:

```
            Timestamp  Value
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
1 2020-02-01 00:00:00    1.0
2 2020-02-02 00:00:00    4.0 # <— clearly a peak here at index [2]
3 2020-02-03 00:00:00    3.0
4 2020-02-03 12:45:00    2.7
5 2020-03-01 00:00:00    2.0
6 2020-04-01 00:00:00    1.0
```

Here, we clearly find a peak at `[2] (index units)`, i.e. at `['2020-02-02T00:00:00.000000000'] (Timestamp units)` with height `[4.] (Value units)`.
Half of the peak maximum can be found at `[2.5] (Value)` and has a width of `[2.78571429] (Index)`!
The width hline should start at `[1.5] (index)` and go to `[4.28571429] (index)` == ??

I think this **clearly demonstrates** that some kind of interpolation needs to take place in order to reveal what `4.285…` means on a time-scale  axis (which is what you need for `hlines()` to work).

The easiest way to do this, is to feed regularly-spaced data into `find_peaks()`, so that you can easily translate the given index back into a date. Whether you interpolate on a daily basis - as I did above - or a minute or second basis is up to you. Just change these two lines to one of the [valid Date offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
df = df.resample('min').mean().reset_index()

# and, within def to_date(x):
return pd.to_datetime(_start) + pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='min')
```

Comment: Hi Asmus, thank you for the awesome answer. May I know why we need to resample? Can we just use the original data? I have updated the question for more details.

Comment: @nilsinelabore it appears you have misunderstood how `find_peaks()` works: you are literally only giving it the array `df["Value"]` as an input (+ parameters), it is completely unaware of the x-axis! Whether you choose the x-axis to be "datetime" (i.e. `2020-12-01`) or indices (i.e. `[0,1,2]` ) or whatever else, it just tries to find _peaks within the given y values_!